# Marketing Cloud Publication Lists not updating on Sales Cloud record

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Apologies if this question has already been asked, but any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I’m currently working with some AMPscript for a custom preference centre in Marketing Cloud. I’ve ran live tests on my own test records and even included a ‘publication lists’ field, and the values appear in that field on the preference centre and update in Sales cloud when I change the values manually.

The only thing that doesn’t appear to be working as expected is the actual preference centre checkboxes. They remain unchecked even though the values are present on my test record and in the ‘publication lists’ field. Even trying to update preferences using these checkboxes doesn’t update the Sales Cloud record. No error is being thrown and I’m getting the ‘Preferences updated successfully’ message.

Here’s the AMPscript below.

```ampscript
        %%[
    
    var @object, @objectFields, @sk, @updateRecord
    
    set @sk = _subscriberKey
    
    if not Empty(@sk) then
    
      if Substring(@sk,1,3)=='003' then
        set @object = 'Contact'
      elseif Substring(@sk,1,3)=='00Q' then  
        set @object = 'Lead'
      elseif Substring(@sk,1,3)=='001' then  
        set @object = 'Account'
      endif
        
      set @firstNameField = 'FirstName'
      set @lastNameField  = 'LastName'
      set @mobileField    = 'MobilePhone'
      set @emailField     = 'Email'
    
      set @firstNameLabel = 'First name'
      set @lastNameLabel  = 'Last name'
      set @mobileLabel    = 'Mobile'
      set @emailLabel     = 'Email Address'
      set @streetLabel    = 'Street'
      set @cityLabel      = 'City'
      set @stateLabel     = 'State'
      set @postcodeLabel  = 'Postcode'
      set @countryLabel   = 'Country'
      set @pubListsLabel  = 'Publication Lists'
    
      set @objectFields   = Concat(@firstNameField, ',',
                                  @lastNameField, ',',
                                  @mobileField, ',',
                                  @emailField)
    
      set @fieldLabels    = Concat(@firstNameLabel, ',',
                                  @lastNameLabel, ',',
                                  @mobileLabel, ',',
                                  @emailLabel, ',',
                                  @streetLabel, ',',
                                  @cityLabel, ',',
                                  @stateLabel, ',',
                                  @postcodeLabel, ',',
                                  @countryLabel, ',',
                                  @pubListsLabel)
    
    if @object=='Contact' then
    
      set @streetField    = 'MailingStreet'
      set @cityField      = 'MailingCity'
      set @stateField     = 'MailingState'
      set @postcodeField  = 'MailingPostalCode'
      set @countryField   = 'MailingCountry'
      set @pubListsField  = 'Publication_Lists__c'
    
      set @objectFields = Concat(@objectFields, ',',
                                @streetField, ',',
                                @cityField, ',',
                                @stateField, ',',
                                @postcodeField, ',',
                                @countryField, ',',
                                @pubListsField)
    
    elseif @object=='Lead' then
    
      set @streetField    = 'Street'
      set @cityField      = 'City'
      set @stateField     = 'State'
      set @postcodeField  = 'PostalCode'
      set @countryField   = 'Country'
      set @pubListsField   = 'Publication_Lists__c'
    
      set @objectFields = Concat(@objectFields, ',',
                                @streetField, ',',
                                @cityField, ',',
                                @stateField, ',',
                                @postcodeField, ',',
                                @countryField, ',',
                                @pubListsField)
    else 
      set @logError = 'object could not be defined'
    endif
    
    if @submitted==true then 
    
      set @firstName = RequestParameter(@firstNameField)
      set @lastName  = RequestParameter(@lastNameField)
      set @mobile    = RequestParameter(@mobileField)
      set @email     = RequestParameter(@emailField)
      set @street    = RequestParameter(@streetField)
      set @city      = RequestParameter(@cityField)
      set @state     = RequestParameter(@stateField)
      set @postcode  = RequestParameter(@postcodeField)
      set @country   = RequestParameter(@countryField)
      set @pubLists   = RequestParameter(@pubListsField)
    
      set @fieldVals = Concat(@firstName, ',', @lastName, ',', @mobile, ',',
                            @email, ',', @street, ',', @city, ',', @state, ',',
                            @postcode, ',',  @country, ',', @publicationLists)
    
      set @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
                          @object, @sk,
                          @firstNameField, @firstName,
                          @lastNameField, @lastName,
                          @mobileField, @mobile,
                          @emailField, @email,
                          @streetField, @street,
                          @cityField, @city,
                          @stateField, @state,
                          @postcodeField, @postcode,
                          @countryField, @country,
                          @pubListsField, @pubLists)
    
      if @updateRecord==0 then
        set @logError = 'failed to update Lead/Contact record'
      endif      
    /* publication list updates */
    
      set @pubLists = concat(
      Iif(RequestParameter("Enews") == "on", "E-News;", ""),
      Iif(RequestParameter("Membership") == "on", "Membership;", ""),
      Iif(RequestParameter("Ticketing") == "on", "Ticketing;", ""),
      Iif(RequestParameter("Smsp") == "on", "SMSP Mailing List;", ""),
    )  
    
      if not empty(@pubLists) then
      set @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
      @object, RequestParameter(@sk),
      "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
      "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
      "Email", RequestParameter("email"),
      "Publication_Lists__c", RequestParameter(@pubLists))
       else
       set @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
      @object, RequestParameter(@sk),
      "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
      "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
      "Email", RequestParameter("email"),
      "fieldsToNull", RequestParameter("Publication_Lists__c"))
    endif
    
      set @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
      "Contact",
      "FirstName,LastName,Email,Publication_Lists__c",
      "Id", "=", @sk )     
      
      if not empty(@pubLists) then
      set @rs = BuildRowSetFromString(@Publication_Lists__c,';')
      Output(rowcount(@rs))
      endif
      
      
      if rowcount(@rs) > 0 then
    
      for @i=1 TO rowcount(@rs) do
      set @val = Field(Row(@rs,@i),1)
      if @val == "E-News" then
      set @Enews = true
      elseif @val == "Membership" then
      set @Membership = true
      elseif @val == "Ticketing" then
      set @Ticketing = true
      elseif @val == "SMSP Mailing List" THEN       
      set @Smsp = true
      endif
      next @i
    
      else
    
      set @Enews = ""
      set @Membership = ""
      set @Ticketing = ""
      set @Smsp = ""
        
    endif
        
    /* making separate calls for resubscribing as updating
      HasOptedOutOfEmail field for unsubscribes handled
      separately by LogUnsubEvent API call */
        if @emailOptOut==0 then
        set @resubscribe = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
                            @object, @sk,
                            'HasOptedOutOfEmail', 0)
        if @resubscribe==0 then
          set @logError = 'failed to update HasOptedOutOfEmail field'
        endif
      endif
    
    else /* form not submitted */
    
      var @rows, @logError
      set @rows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(@object, @objectFields, 'Id', '=', @sk )
    
      if RowCount(@rows) == 1 then
        var @row, @firstName, @lastName, @mobile, @email,
            @street, @city, @state, @postcode, @country, @publicationLists
        set @row = Row(@rows, 1)
        set @firstName = Field(@row, @firstNameField)
        set @lastName  = Field(@row, @lastNameField)
        set @mobile    = Field(@row, @mobileField)
        set @email     = Field(@row, @emailField)
        set @street    = Field(@row, @streetField)
        set @city      = Field(@row, @cityField)
        set @state     = Field(@row, @stateField)
        set @postcode  = Field(@row, @postcodeField)
        set @country   = Field(@row, @countryField)
        set @pubLists   = Field(@row, @pubListsField)
    
    
        set @fieldVals = Concat(@firstName, ',', @lastName, ',', @mobile, ',',
                                @email, ',', @street, ',', @city, ',', @state, ',',
                                @postcode, ',', @country, ',', @pubLists)
    
      else
        set @logError = 'Unable to retrieve record'
      endif
    
    endif /* end form not submitted */
    
    /* stuff fields into array */
    var @formFields, @fieldRows, @countFields, @fieldType,
        @fieldObject, @labelRows, @valueRows, @fieldRow, 
        @fieldName, @labelRow
    
    set @fieldRows = BuildRowSetFromString(@objectFields,',')
    set @labelRows = BuildRowSetFromString(@fieldLabels,',')
    set @valueRows = BuildRowSetFromString(@fieldVals,',')
    set @countFields = RowCount(@fieldRows)
    
    for @i = 1 to @countFields do
    
      set @fieldRow = Row(@fieldRows, @i) 
      set @fieldName = Field(@fieldRow, 1)
      set @labelRow = Row(@labelRows, @i) 
      set @fieldLabel = Field(@labelRow, 1)
      set @valueRow = Row(@valueRows, @i) 
      set @fieldValue = Field(@valueRow, 1)
    
      if @fieldName == 'Birthdate' then
        set @fieldType = 'date'
      elseif @fieldName == 'Email' then
        set @fieldType = 'email'
      else
        set @fieldType = 'text'
      endif
      set @fieldObject = Concat(@fieldObject, 
      '{"Name":"', @fieldName, '",
        "Label":"', @fieldLabel, '",
        "Value":"', @fieldValue, '",
        "Type":"', @fieldType, '"}',
        iif(@i == @countFields, '', ','))
    next
    
    set @formFields = Concat('[', @fieldObject, ']')
    
    /* set @logError = 'test error' */
    
    var @url
    set @url = RequestParameter('PAGEURL')
    
    endif /* end if not Empty(@sk) */
    
      Output(Concat("First Name: ", @firstName))
      Output(Concat("Last Name: ", @lastName))
      Output(Concat("Subscriber Key: ", @sk))
      Output(Concat("Publication Lists: ", @pubLists))
    
    ]%%
```

Comment: What exactly isn’t working for you - do you mean the SFMC Publication Lists or the custom SF field called Publication_Lists__c?

Comment: It’s the publication lists. They don’t seem to be checked even though the values are present on the contact record and sales cloud record.

Comment: I don’t see anything in your script that would update Publication Lists, you need to add it in AMPscript. Publication Lists are not connected to Sales Cloud ootb.

Comment: Thanks zuzannamj. Would the ampscript be similar to the set @pubLists, but use listId instead?

Comment: No, you would have to call the SOAP API using AMPscript, take a look at the example here - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252746/unsubscribe-an-user-from-publication-list-using-ampscript-in-marketing-cloud